# Ошибка: Не удалось скопировать файл obj\ <путь> в bin\<путь> так как этот файл используется другим процессом

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Всем привет! Возникла проблема при компиляции кода в Visual Studio 2019 на языке С# Текст ошибки приведен в вопросе

Проблема в том что я не понимаю где конкретно этот файл нужно найти и закрыть. В диспетчере задач я смотрел, там отображаеться лишь браузер и сама програма Visual Studio 2019, а также помимо них отображаеться еще и Visual Studio Installer. Подскажите пожалуйста где именно этот файл нужно искать и как сделать так чтобы после последующих сборок не возникало этой ошибки (желательно объяснение с пошаговим алгоритмом). Большое спасибо за советы :)

Comment: А что это за файл? Как он используется программой, которую Вы пытаетесь откомпилировать?

Comment: Причины могут быть разными. Одна из возможных причин: ваше приложение висит в памяти (бесконечный цикл, или WinForms со скрытой формой). Найти его в Диспетчере задач и убить.

Comment: А как он называется? Как проект? Просто когда я пытаюсь удалить .exe файл с названием проекта то он пишет что могут потеряться данные

Comment: Может ли этот файл называться как проект и иметь расширение .exe?

Comment: Закрыть проект, полностью удалить папки bin и obj, открыть проект

Comment: Иногда помогает только перегрузить комп ))  Но закрыть и открыть проект часто уже достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Процесс, который тебе нужно закрыть, называется так же как и твой проект и находится он в фоновых процессах диспетчера задач. Если будешь запускать с отладкой, то это фиксится. Причину возникновения не знаю, сам столкнулся с этой проблемой.